# Merging two sorted arrays with 'for' loop... how to stop 'i' from increasing at end of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops

I want to merge two sorted arrays into one sorted array e.g. [1, 3, 6, 7, 11] and [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10] merge to become [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]. However, I want to do this without any javascript array methods like .push() or .concat() so I become more familiar with the underlying logic in these methods. Here is my code.

```
const array1 = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11];
const array2 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10];

const set = (arr, index, value) => {
  return arr[index] = value;
}

const mergeArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let loopLength = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? arr1.length : 
  arr2.length;
  let mergedArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < loopLength; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] <= arr2[i]) {
      console.log(i);
      mergedArr = [...mergedArr, set(mergedArr, i, arr1[i]), set(mergedArr, i + 1, arr2[i])];
    } else {
      console.log(i);
      mergedArr = [...mergedArr, set(mergedArr, i, arr2[i]), set(mergedArr, i + 1, arr1[i])];
    }
  }
  return mergedArr;
}

mergeArrs(array1, array2);
```

Here is what's output to the console:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
=> [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10, undefined ]
```

Bits of my function are correct, I think, but I encounter problems such as the arrays are only merged/sorted in relation to their original position. E.g. arrayOne[4] = 11 and arrayTwo[4] = 9, so at first, it correctly goes [..., 9, 11, ...] but then because arrayOne doesn't have an index of 5 and arrayTwo does, arrayTwo[5] = 10, the 10 is tacked onto the array after the 11:  [..., 9, 11, 10, undefined] and the undefined is there because the first array doesn't have an index of 5 so it's undefined... idk... I just can't seem to get this :(

I'd really appreciate any help, thx

Comment: Note that with values like [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] and [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], you need two independent indications of how much of each array has been processed even before reaching the end of either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take some `while` loops, because you can independently check the indices and push the values as desired and increment the index for the pushed value.

The first `while` loop checks both indices and contains a check for getting a smaller value.

The other both `while` loops are necessary to add the leftover values to the `merged` array.

```js
var array1 = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11],
    array2 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10],
    merged = [],
    i = 0,
    j = 0;

while (i < array1.length && j < array2.length) {
    if (array1[i] < array2[j]) {
        merged = [...merged, array1[i++]];
        continue;
    }
    merged = [...merged, array2[j++]];
}

while (i < array1.length) merged = [...merged, array1[i++]];
while (j < array2.length) merged = [...merged, array2[j++]];

console.log(...merged);
```

Another approach

```js
function merge([v, ...a], [w, ...b]) {
    return v < w
        ? [v, ...(a.length ? merge(a, [w, ...b]) : [w, ...b])]
        : [w, ...(b.length ? merge([v, ...a], b) : [v, ...a])];
}

console.log(...merge([1, 3, 6, 7, 11], [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Done some changes in your code and it is working now.

```js
const array1 = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11];
    const array2 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10];

    const set = (arr, index, value) => {
        return arr[index] = value;
    }

    const mergeArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
        let loopLength = arr1.length + arr2.length;
        let mergedArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= loopLength; i++) {
            if (arr1.length && arr2.length) {
                if (arr1[0] <= arr2[0])
                    mergedArr = [...mergedArr, set(mergedArr, i, arr1.shift())];

                else
                    mergedArr = [...mergedArr, set(mergedArr, i, arr2.shift())];
            }
            else if (arr1.length) {
                mergedArr = [...mergedArr, set(mergedArr, i, arr1.shift())];
            }
            else if (arr2.length) {
                mergedArr = [...mergedArr, set(mergedArr, i, arr2.shift())];
            }
        }
        return mergedArr;
    }

    console.log(mergeArrs(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something with a while loop would do the job. You just have to compare each smaller element as long as the arrays are not empty. And then you increment the right index (the one of the array containing the selected value), leaving the other unchanged.

```js
function mergeArrs(arr1, arr2) {
    let i = 0,
        j = 0,
        k = 0,
        mergedArr = [];

    //compare as long as they're not empty
    while (i != arr1.length && j != arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[i] > arr2[j])
            mergedArr[k++] = arr2[j++];
        else
            mergedArr[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }
    // empty the remainder
    while (i < arr1.length)
        mergedArr[k++] = arr1[i++];
    while (j < arr2.length)
        mergedArr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    return mergedArr;
}
```